# Why does an FCM error appear when calling a firebase function

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

So I am calling a firebase function through AngularFire like so:

```js
const response = await this.aFunctions.httpsCallable<void, ResponseType>('funcName')().toPromise();
```

This works when deployed to firebase (hosting), but in the local environment (using `ionic serve`), it throws this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8100/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8100/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8100/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8100/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
```

I am not using FCM in any way in this project. Do you have any clue why this happens?

Comment: That error doesn't look like it's related to the code you're showing.  Are you sure it's impacting the way the code works?

Comment: It does appear exactly when calling any function. doesnt matter which. I am not sure what causes it though, but I am positive that there is no FCM involved in this project. @DougStevenson

Comment: I would just ignore it if the code is otherwise working fine.

Comment: The problem is that it isnt working fine. Other projects with similar setups (ionic/angular + firebase) dont throw me this error, so I cant just ignore it. It only works when deployed to firebase. otherwise calling a function throws this error. @DougStevenson

Comment: If you have a bug report, then I suggest contacting Firebase support for assistance.  There's just not enough information here to work with.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I dont ask for a bugfix, but maybe someone has had a similar problem. I doubt that I can contact anyone using the support formular. Intresting thing is that, if I add a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file - even if it is invalid, I get a CORS error instead of the FCM error. @DougStevenson

Comment: This is happening to me as well. There is a thread on it here:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2496

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, I solved it by **commenting out the messagingSenderId**.

```js
firebase: {
  apiKey: 'XXXXX',
  authDomain: 'XXXXX',
  databaseURL: 'XXXXX',
  projectId: 'XXXXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXXXX',
  // messagingSenderId: 'XXXXX',   **<== comment out this**
  appId: 'XXXXX'
}
```

My case is a bit different and strange.
I need to deploy an Angular project to firebase hosting.

**Code:**

```js
const ob = this.functions.httpsCallable('api-name')({});
ob.subscribe((data)=>{
  //do something here
});
```

**Error:**

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker.......
```

**Environment:**

- Local: OK
- firebase hosting default Domain(projectName.web.app): Error
- firebase hosting default Domain(projectName.firebaseapp.com): OK

I don't know the reason, but hope it can help you and others who have the similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I fixed it by addressing the importing of Firebase throughout my app.

// This import loads the firebase namespace along with all its type information.
`import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
`import 'firebase/auth';`
`import 'firebase/database';`

I was able to remove the firebase-messaging-sw.js file and all onCall functions are working properly.

I previously had a mix of:

`import firebase from 'firebase;`

`import * as firebase from 'firebase'`

Standardizing everything to import firebase from 'firebase/app' + the subsequent packages you need
`import 'firebase/functions'`

Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a better answer but in my case I support FCM so I need to supply the `messagingSenderId` (though commenting out did fix the issue w/ calling my cloud func).

It seems if you support FCM & want to use `htttpsCallable` you NEED to get your FCM token first ‍♂️

In my case moving this before my cloud func call fixed my issue:

```
    const vapidKey = 'yourkey'
    const token = await firebase.messaging().getToken({ vapidKey })
    const result = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updateEventReaction');
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mixin between firease 9 modular and compat library, it may cause some indesirable behaviour.

For example, if you're using modular library for firebase messaging, and compat library for your functions

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';
```

Then in my case calling a function after registering an FCM token were causing the error you're having

So either migrate all your firebase library calls to modular version, or keep the compat version of the messaging library