# Calling an onCall function in Firebase Functions using AngularFire results in a 404 error, while returning the expected result

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have created a few onCall cloud functions using Firebase. These functions interact with Stripe through the API. When I use AngularFire, or more specifically, AngularFireFunctions to call these said cloud functions, I receive the error message `A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.` in Chrome developer console. Yet, the expected result is received with no problem and the Firebase console displays a 200 response with no error messages or warnings. The project is entirely hosted on Firebase.

The 404 error also does not display a file that it is connected to in the console as such errors typically do within that console.

**UPDATE**

I also feel it is relevant to include, the Stripe developer logs in the dashboard reflect no errors, but a successfull call upon checking.

I have also tried to remove the call to Stripe in the cloud function and simply only return a string `return 'The customer ID is:'+ ${data.customerId}+'. Thank you.'` and still received the same error message.

I have also tried this solution, https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1933#issuecomment-432910986 with the following code being placed inside `app.module.ts` however, am unable to find where `FunctionsRegionToken` would be defined to be able to import it.

```
providers: [
  { provide: FunctionsRegionToken, useValue: 'us-central1' }
]
```

Although, I'm not sure how changing the region to the same region the function is being called from currently would make any difference.

**When you explore the `Network` tab of the developer console and visit the page that calls the function, you see that something is trying to call `http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js` which doesn't exist. The amount of calls to this file and the errors in the console coincide with each other which leads me to believe they are related.**

**END OF UPDATE**

I have tried to add `CORS` to my cloud function (and am using it in onRequest functions), I've tried rewriting my cloud function, and even tried changing the client side function that calls the onCall to no avail. The only way to remove the error is to remove the call to the function, thus I've narrowed it down to something with the AngularFireFunctions.

What I am using and the versions

```
Angular V13
Firebase 9.6.7
Angular Fire 7.2.1
Node 16.13.1
```

What follows is my code, broken up into sections.

**Cloud function**

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
admin.initializeApp();
const firebaseApp = admin.app();
const firebaseDB = firebaseApp.firestore();
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe(functions.config().stripe.key);

export const retrieveCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async(data) => {
    if(data.customerId) {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(data.customerId);
        if(customer) {
            return customer;
        } else {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An unknown error occurred, please try again.'); 
        }
    } else {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'A customer ID must be provided.');
    }
});
```

**Angular Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BillingService {

  constructor( private aff: AngularFireFunctions, private afs: AngularFirestore ) { }

  RetrieveCustomer(customerId:string) {
    const callable = this.aff.httpsCallable('retrieveCustomer');
    return callable({
      customerId: customerId
    });
  }

}
```

**Angular Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BillingService } from 'src/app/shared/services/billing/billing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-billing-settings',
  templateUrl: './billing-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./billing-settings.component.css']
})
export class BillingSettingsComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  public stripeCustomer!: any;

  constructor( private billingService: BillingService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.billingService.RetrieveCustomer('cus_LGRX8TPVF3Xh0w').subscribe((customer:any) => {
      console.log(customer);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: By utilizing this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641275/why-does-an-fcm-error-appear-when-calling-a-firebase-function I was able to resolve the issue for the moment. Commenting out the `messagingSenderId` in the firebase config, makes the error disappear. I'm still not sure as to why calling a firebase cloud function results in trying to call a service worker for firebase messaging when I'm not even using messaging yet.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve it? I have the same problem. I tried commenting out `messageSenderId` and it didn't work for me.